# IAP: Restrict access to admin allowing open access to public website

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iap

I have a web application with a www.domain.tld/admin namespace, which I want to have protected with Google IAP.

However, I don't want to restrict access to our public-facing website, at www.domain.tld.

Is there any strategy to leave access fully open to our website, while restricting access to "admin"?

Comment: There's probably a good reason not to use a separate subdomain e.g. admin.domain.tld -- can you add that context to your question?

Comment: Where is your code running? App Engine std or flexible? Compute Engine?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible if you are using GCLB to send the traffic to GCE or GKE:

1. Create two different Backend Services in GCLB, called "public_site" and "admin_site." You could even point them to same servers, although it's better security to have them be as separate as possible.
2. Set up GCLB with a URLMap that sends /admin to admin_site and everything else to public_site.
3. Enable IAP for admin_site only.

This takes advantage of the fact that IAP is enabled/disabled on a per-backend basis.